# How can i get websites title and current url with python and webkit

Tags: python, webkit, gtk

I'm trying to create a webrowser with python, gtk and webkit but i've ran into a big problem... I cant seem to be able to get the websites title and url so I can then place them in there respected places (tab, entry bar.) I found an example of getting the title working here: https://gist.github.com/kklimonda/890640#file-pybrowser-py but I'm finding it hard to implement it into my code, Ive Manged to get it in to the function:

```
    def _title_changed(self, webview, frame, title):
        print(title)
```

by calling:

```
    web.connect("title-changed", self._title_changed)
```

But i can't get it from that function to the one I need it in:

```
    def _add_tab(self, button):
            tab = Gtk.HBox()
            label = Gtk.Label(title) # This is the line I need it in
            label.show()
            tab.pack_start(label, False, False, 0)
            close_tab = Gtk.ToolButton(Gtk.STOCK_CLOSE)
            close_tab.connect('clicked', self.remove_book, notebook)
            close_tab.show()
            tab.pack_start(close_tab, False, False, 0)

            frame.add(scw)
            frame.show()

            notebook.append_page(frame, tab)
```

I've thought of adding the tab code to the _title_changed function but the tab code is already in a function being called by:

```
    add_tab.connect("clicked", self.add_page)
```

And the title got lost in all of the arguments because I wasn't sure which one it would be.

This Issue mainly came are because I'm not that used to Gtk, I will be very grateful to any solutions, Thanks :-)

Comment: You store the `WebView` and the `Gtk.Label` in a dict upon tab creation. If the `title-changed` signal is emitted, you can look in the dict for the `WebView`, get the `Gtk.Label` for the tab, and change its text.

Comment: Thanks that has really helped :-)